# How can I add score to ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am working on an web application in asp.net core and I have a user information component in my webpage in which i display information about the user (currently only the username). I want to implement a score functionality and I was wondering what would be the easiest method to do that. I added a score property to the user table but I have to pass the model to the controller to access it and it doesn't seem very efficient. I searched the web but I am a beginner and didn't managed to find something that catches my eye.Any ideas?

Comment: You should add property to your DB model and then pass it to controller. Wht is not efficient about it?

Comment: I did it like this after all. I thought that it wasn't efficient because I would have to pass the User model for every page but didn't found any solution

Comment: If you add the username as claim then you won't have to query the database but read the claim instead. But for scores you'll need to query the database as scores change.